# insert css to ruby app - namely, rtl support to gitlab

Tags: css, ruby, sass, gitlab, right-to-left

Couldn't find anything on the subject, even for the more general "ruby" and "css" terms (as opposed to "gitlab" and "rtl"). I apologize if missed an existing answer.

My problem is a complete lack of knowledge in ruby, and of time to learn it. I am not new to programming though, and know a thing or two about web programming also (played with django a little).

We are interested in deploying Gitlab on a server in my workplace, but we need it to display hebrew text properly. We don't need Gitlab translated! only our comments and issues to be created in Hebrew. I believe this can be achieved by applying the following css code to the pages (all of them, why not):

```
div.event-note   {
            direction:   rtl;
            text-align:   left;
}

div.issue-actions   {
            left:   30px;
}

div.issue-title   {
            direction:   rtl;
            padding-bottom:   5px;
            text-align:   right;
}

div.note-text   p   {
            direction:   rtl;
            text-align:   right;
}

div.state-label.state-label-green   {
            float:   left;
}

div.state-label.state-label-red   {
            float:   left;
}

div.wiki   {
            direction:   rtl;
}

div.wiki   ol,   div.wiki   ul   {
            padding-right:   40px;
}

div.wiki   pre   {
            direction:   ltr;
}

h4.box-title   {
            direction:   rtl;
}

input.input-xxlarge.js-gfm-input   {
            direction:   rtl;
}

textarea.input-xxlarge.js-gfm-input   {
            direction:   rtl;
}

textarea.note_text.js-note-text.js-gfm-input.turn-on   {
            direction:   rtl;
}
```

(thanks to: http://stylebot.me/styles/5581)

But, my attempts to add this code failed (that is, the Hebrew text is shown bad on the site).

I am using a bitnami appliance of Gitlab on Ubuntu 14.04 (download [here](https://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab/virtual-machine))
I've tried the following:

1. Added this code as it is to /opt/bitnami/gitlab/htdocs/public/static.css
2. Converted it to scss using css2compass, saved in an .scss file and added an import to it to /opt/bitnami/gitlab/htdocs/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

Am I doing the right thing? am I missing a compilation process?
Any help will be much appreciated, but helping me understand what to do is beneficial as I will need to maintain the app over time.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here's the scss code I got from the above css -

```
div {
    &.event-note {
        direction: rtl;
        text-align: left;
    }
    &.issue-actions {
        left: 30px;
    }
    &.issue-title {
        direction: rtl;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        text-align: right;
    }
    &.state-label {
        &.state-label-green {
            float: left;
        }
        &.state-label-red {
            float: left;
        }
    }
    &.wiki {
        direction: rtl;
        ol {
            padding-right: 40px;
        }
        ul {
            padding-right: 40px;
        }
    }
    &.note-text p {
        direction: rtl;
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

If someone can confirm it's good for ruby/gitlab it would be nice...

Comment: "My attempts failed" does not explain what is wrong.  Is there an error?  What is the error?  Did you look at the compiled CSS to verify that it is producing the output you expected?

Comment: Thanks, Mr. angry man. As I mentioned I don't know ruby. From your comment I understand I should be doing some kind of compilation. Here's what I've found on gitlab's site - https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/ will this do?

Comment: Don't want to be annoying but it's kind of urgent. Calling you, @cimmanon.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer elsewhere - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found the answer here:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-to-recompile-assets-for-gitlab/24644

quote:

> Hi,
>
> You can compile the application assets with the following command.
>   Note you have to start the "use_gitlab" script before running these
>   command if you are using the native installer.
>
> ```
> sudo su git
> cd /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs
> bin/rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
> ```

I did this and rebooted the machine and RTL was displayed in an acceptable manner.
Assuming there is a way to re-deploy the app without rebooting the server, and after not finding it although trying, I will mark as accepted any answer which will add this part to my solution.

Thanks.